# Mongodb: update elements of multiple arrays in same document at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have used `$push` to update elements of one array. But when I tried to update elements of multiple array keeping `$push` with comma separated values like below, it is showing an error. How is it done?

```
var conditions = { some condition };
var update = { $push : {Feedback : { Feedbacks:req.body.Feedbacks}}, {Strength : { Strengths:req.body.Strengths}}};
var options = { multi : true};

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
```

Schema is:

```
Model : {

Field1 : {
    type:Number 
},

Field2: { 
     type : String
 },

Feedback : {
        type: Array,
        Default:[]
    },

    Strength : {
        type: Array,
        Default: [],
    }
};
```

Note: It is working for one array update (if I keep only Feedback array after push) but not for multiple arrays update. How to do for multiple arrays?

Comment: Thanks @Janan. It is working now. I have kept flower brackets in incorrect way before.

Answer (score 1):

[Push to two separate arrays in one update call in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593607/push-to-two-separate-arrays-in-one-update-call-in-mongodb)

```
Model.update(
   conditions, 
   updates,
   options,
   callback
)

var updates = 
{
   $push : 
   {
      Feedback : { $each: req.body.Feedbacks },
      Strength : { $each: req.body.Strengths }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   { $push: { <field1>: <value1>,
              <field2>: <value2> } }
```

i.e

```
      $push : 
       {
         Feedback : { $each: req.body.Feedbacks },
         Strength : { $each: req.body.Strengths } }
```